# javascript: determing the structure of an object programmatically

Tags: javascript

I am building javascript (nodejs) integration with a remote service. The service returns inconsistently formatted results, and from within javascript, I am battling to determine how to switch my formatting based on the response.

The 2 formats are shown below, the first is when Parent has a single child, and the 2nd is where Parent has >1 children:

```
var single = { "Parent" : { "name" : "foo" } }
var multi = { "Parent" : [ { "name" : "foo" }, { "name" : "bar" } ] }
```

So when I try and parse the results in js, accessing a child attribute of "name", I get inconsistent results:

```
for (var i in single) {
    console.log("child name: " + single[i].name;
}

for (var i in multi.Parent) {
    console.log("child name: " + multi.Parent[i].name;
}
```

What would the best way be to determine whether I am getting a single or multi result back? I tried "typeof response", hoping to get an "Array" for multi, but that didn't work.The object is initially received as a string, but converted to an object using `JSON.parse(responseString)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use `constructor` property.

```
>> single.Parent.constructor == Array
false
>> multi.Parent.constructor == Array
true
```

Comment: @yakxxx: yes it is, but in the end: `x instanceof Object` will _always_ be true, except for constants, so be careful

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem In this case he could do `x instanceof Array` which will be true for arrays.

Comment: @yakxxx: Sure, but what I meant to say was that, when using `instanceof` you have to be careful: `switch (true){ case x instanceof Array: return 'array'; case x instanceof Object: return 'object';}` will perform as expected, but when the first case is `x instanceof Object: return 'object';`, it won't. That's something to be weary of. In an environment with fairly long inheritance chains, and many custom object constructors, `instanceof` is more error prone

Comment: For my use case, instanceof works great, although I can see why the .constructor method may be more portable.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the "name" property to be defined.

```
var single = { "Parent" : { "name" : "foo" } };
var multi = { "Parent" : [ { "name" : "foo" }, { "name" : "bar" } ] };

console.log(single.Parent.name == undefined); // True
console.log(multi.Parent.name == undefined);  // False
```

Cf: http://jsfiddle.net/QhFvP/

Answer (score 0):

`typeof response` will tell you that both are Objects, since Array is an Object.

You can try to get multi.Parent.length which will give you a number if its an Array or undefined if it's an JSON Object. So,

```
for (var i = 0; i < multi.Parent.length; i++){
    console.log("child name", multi.Parent[i].name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an error you are doing here. Both responses in the first place are objects. It is `Parent` field which is object or list depending on number of results. You shouldn't do:

```
single[i].name
```

Insted you should write:

```
single.Parent[i].name
```

So to check if you have single or multiple response you have to check

```
if(response.Parent instanceof Array){}
```

Note usage of `instanceof` instead of `typeof`. And BTW there is no problem with constructing object from text with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
// Using instanceof
if (response.Parent instanceof Array !== true) response.Parent = [response.Parent]
// More robust method, using .constructor:
if (response.Parent.constructor !== Array) response.Parent = [response.Parent]

// Continue with multi processing 
for (var i in response.Parent) {}
```

Thanks for all the feedback.